# Why Is This Div Creating a Line Break Here?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make this paragraph line up properly but for some reason the Div containing either the subheading or underline div displaces the first few words. I've tried setting different positions and wrapping them in a containing div but it won't stop displacing the text.

I've included my html and css below, I'm not sure how to get around this.

```css
  .concerned #subheading-container {
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;
        right: 5.5%;
        top: 10px;
    }

    .right-underline {
        position: relative;
        background: #B9D4EC;
        width: 52.5%;
        height: 2.75px;
        float: right;
        top: 7.5px;
    }

    .subheading-blue {
        position: relative;
        color: #2A5073;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 11.25px;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .paragraph-blue {
        color: #2A5073;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 9.75px;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 120%;
    }

    #concerned-text-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 0%;
        /* height: 1000px; */
        text-align: right;
        top: 15%;
    }

    #dont-be {
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;
        top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="concerned">

        <div id="subheading-container">

            <!-- Concerned? Heading -->
            <h class="subheading-blue">Concerned About the Process?</h>

        </div>

        <div class="underline-container">

            <!-- Blue Underline -->
            <div class="right-underline">

        </div>


        <div id="concerned-text-container">

            <!-- Don't worry text -->
            <h class="paragraph-blue" id="dont-be">
                The text
            </h>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of how this renders?

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Comment: There is no such thing as a the `<h>` element

Comment: You didn't close the right-underline div.

    <!-- Blue Underline -->
    <div class="right-underline">
    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The `.concerned` tag must have `float()` property assigned rather than all of the `div`'s separately.
2. Your issues mainly occur due to `.right-underline`. If you are working with multiple `divs` it's always helpful to understand the DOM structure.

I have modified your code to align the texts and div to the right, however please go through the comments in the code to understand what issues exist in your code.

P.S. `h` tags don't exist, you probably want to use `h[1-6]` tags for headings. 
You have missed out closing the `.right-underline` div.

```css
    .concerned{
        display: block;
        float: right;
    }
    
    #subheading-container {
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;
        /* right: 5.5%;       Causes a shift of the text towards center of the screen */
        top: 10px;
    }

    .right-underline {
        position: relative;
        background: #B9D4EC;
        width: 52.5%;
        height: 2.75px;
        top: 7.5px;
    }

    .subheading-blue {
        position: relative;
        color: #2A5073;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 11.25px;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .paragraph-blue {
        color: #2A5073;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 9.75px;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 120%;
    }

    #concerned-text-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 0%;
        /* height: 1000px; */
        
        /*text-align: right;      Aligns "The text" to page right*/
        top: 15%;
    }

    #dont-be {
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;
        top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="concerned">

        <div id="subheading-container">

            <!-- Concerned? Heading -->
            <h class="subheading-blue">Concerned About the Process?</h>

        </div>

        <div class="underline-container">

            <!-- Blue Underline -->
            <div class="right-underline">

        </div>


        <div id="concerned-text-container">

            <!-- Don't worry text -->
            <h class="paragraph-blue" id="dont-be">
                The text
            </h>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this now. Cheers for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @a_lame If it was useful, kindly appreciate the effort and upvote it for future users as well. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that there is no < h >-tag in html and that you have an unclosed < div >-tag, the line break is created, because you have set your right-underline to float right and a fixed width of 52.2%.

I'm not sure what you actually are trying to do but if you remove your float, your words are not going to be displaced anymore